# Make virtual function final without giving new definition

Tags: c++, c++11, virtual, final

In my class hierarchy there are numerous virtual functions that can be overridden. My Window class for example has many functions that don't need to be changed but should also not be overridden in the future. So I want to add the final keyword to some of Window's functions, but I don't need to redefine any of them because they already work like I want them to.

I'm currently just calling the base class function in the final redefinition but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this that doesn't require even doing that.

Example Code:

```
class Control {
    virtual void foo();
};
class Window : public Control {
    void foo() final; // I don't want to have to define this because it does the same thing.
};
class AnotherControl : public Control {
    void foo() override; // I do want to change what the function does with this control.
};
```

Comment: it will be more helpful to see example code, preferably a [mcve].

Comment: Sounds like what I would do, though, I would wonder how you ended up in this situation

Comment: Can you mark the ones that shouldn't change `final` in the base class? It won't affect your behaviour. It'll give a few errors here and there if you overrode them.

Comment: Why are these functions `virtual` if they "should also not be overridden in the future"?

Comment: @NicolBolas because other classes that extend the base class _do_ need to override that function.

Comment: I don't see other way than `void foo() override final { Control::foo(); }`...

Comment: @Jarod42 That's what I figured. But the override keyword is unnecessary when using the final keyword.